# asXML not behaving correctly

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I may be missing something really obvious but this

```
<?php
$string = <<<XML
<a>
 <b>
  <c>text</c>
  <c>stuff</c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <c>code</c>
 </d>
</a>
XML;

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);

echo $xml->asXML();
```

is supposed to output the below according to [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php).

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
 <b>
  <c>text</c>
  <c>stuff</c>
 </b>
 <d>
  <c>code</c>
 </d>
</a>
```

Not the case, it is, in fact, outputting the below (for me at least). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
text stuff code
```

Comment: If you're seeing this output in a browser, view the source of the resulting page. This behaves as expected. https://3v4l.org/YsmBR

Comment: Thank you! Been trying to work that out for hours.